# Windows batch file deletes and recopies files WAY too fast - should take 15+ seconds, takes < 1 second. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, script

I wrote a script that checks to see if a folder exists, and if so, empties it.
it then waits 5 seconds, then proceeds to recopy new (or maybe the same) files back into the folder.

When the folders don't already exist, it'll take 15-20 seconds to copy the files.  but when the folders already exist, I can watch them being emptied, I see it wait, then I see it zip through the copy commands in less than 1 second.  And the files show up in the list.

Can someone explain this to me?  It would almost appear that the copy is actually looking to see if the file HAD existed, and if so, if it was somehow identical, it just restores the file rather than recopy it.

I haven't tested the "restore" theory, but wanted to know if this was even probable (it's scary either way).

I added the 5 second pause thinking that maybe the drive needed time to stabilize.

Thanks in advance.

Example of script:

@echo off

```
if exist c:\some\folder erase /q c:\some\folder
erase /q C:\another\folder\file*.exe
ping -n 6 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul

copy /y some\folder\sample.exe c:\some\folder\sample.exe
copy /y another\folder\file001.exe c:\some\folder\file001.exe
```

make your test files large so they take time to copy, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Are you saying it's working too fast for your liking? I'm not sure what the question is. Can't you just check the file and see if it changed as you expected? What are you testing?

Comment: No, I'm saying if it takes 15 seconds to copy it the first time, why doesn't it take 15 seconds the second time, after the files have been deleted.

Comment: by the way, I replaced "erase" with "rmdir /s" and it does the same thing.

Comment: the goal is to update a folder with a new set of files, and keep it clean.  It will frequently be the case that the new files will be identical to the old files, but just in case, all files are removed and new files copied in to prevent buildup.

Comment: Well the data from files is still there even when deleted. You can recover it using a program like Recuva until that file has been overwritten by other data. I understand what you're asking now and it may be the case that it can "restore" the data.

Comment: Yep, I understand the "delete" process really just marks the file as deleted.  But it seems like it would be documented that the system is designed to save time by just restoring identical files (and then they'd have to explain how they determine that).  And then have to prove how much faster it is to compare two files rather than just transfer one.  Doesn't seem likely to me.

Comment: I'm not arguing, by the way - baffled, and not sure if I can actually trust the new copies to be correct.

Comment: deleting deletes the link to the file. Don't assume what they "have to" and "don't have to" document. Maybe test by erasing the file permanently then copying. There are programs to do that proper deletion

Comment: I doubt Microsoft or other creators would think that information is necessary for the average user. I don't know the inner workings of Windows but perhaps that information could be found online.

Comment: you have relative paths eg `some\folder\sample.exe`  what directory are you in there? and re what is happening, perhaps another possibility is a cache somewhere maybe hdd designed but you need to test erasing the file properly with an erasing properly program

Comment: I've spent the last hour trying to duplicate what I saw happen multiple times, but when specifically trying to test it, I can't make it happen, on FAT or NTFS, after a format, after a delete, or without the delete.  Going to call this one dead.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are witnessing the filesystem cache doing its job.

First of all, when you copy a file the computer must read that file into memory before it can write it back out to the copy.  Reading that file represents a time cost, so the in-memory copy is kept around in the cache in case you need it again.  Like if you open that file you just copied, or you copy it somewhere else.  The OS does not have to waste time reading it from the disk again.

Second of all, the cake is a lie.  When a file gets "written", it does not actually go to the disk.  It goes instead to a memory buffer which then gets committed to the disk at some later time (usually immediately but not necessarily -- it depends on how busy the disk is).  Either way, the OS reports that the file has finished copying when in fact it has not.

Both read caching and write buffering are optimization techniques that all modern operating systems use.  In your case (assuming nothing went wrong and the files are identical), your script is hitting a sweet spot.  The file(s) merely got copied from one block of cache memory to another block of buffer memory and that's why it didn't take very long.

Incidentally... this is why you should never turn a computer off without properly shutting it down or remove a flash drive without unmounting it.  Part of that process is to commit the write cache to the disk.